# Merging multiple data frames in a loop

Tags: r, loops

I have such a data frame(df) with ID's

```
ID
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

I have such data frames df1 and df2:

df1:

```
ID  x
3   656
5   678
```

df2:

```
ID x
1  45
2  954
6  1245
```

I want to merge df1 and df2 onto df. The resulting data frame will be:

```
ID  x
1   45
2   954
3   656
4   NA
5   678
6   1245
```

In my real problem, I have a lot of data frames to merge with df(df also have a lot of more ID's). I want to this merging procedure in a loop. How can I do that in R? I will bevery glad for any help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What did you search? What did you find? What did you try?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091303/simultaneously-merge-multiple-data-frames-in-a-list

Comment: Your example, in which all dataframes contain only one column called `x` besides the `id`, it looks like you don't actually need to merge, just to bind the rows together (unless you want to keep observations with no value in `x` as `NA`). Look at `rbind_all`.

Comment: using `dplyr` library you can do just `df %>% left_join(df1) %>% left_join(df2)` or maybe `bind_rows(df1, df2)` if you dont need rows where `x` is `NA`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

create the 'x' column with all NA values in your first data.frame

```
df[,"x"] <- NA
```

use your ID column to name the rows of your first data.frame

```
rownames (df) <- df$ID
```

and then use this rownames to replace the 'x' column just in the      desired rows depending of each of your other datasets

```
df[df1$ID, "x"] <- df1$x

df[df2$ID, "x"] <- df2$x
```

This will keep the NA values in the 'x' column as in your example.